# Could help but curse(d)?

Tags: grammar

I have a sentence here:

> Tom couldn't help but cursed when he saw Sam dressed like that.

I feel like there's something off about the sentence, but I don't know how to change it to make it sound better. It's meant to be in past tense, so if I change it to

> Tom couldn't help but curse when he saw Sam dressed like that.

It sounds better, but I not sure if the sentence would still be in past tense. It seems more "presenty".

Answer (score 3):

The verb following *to help* is not a finite form, so it has no tense at all. It is untensed. It must be non-finite — usually infinitive, sometimes gerund. It can have a subject but does not require one.

- She helps **see** things clearly.
- She helps me **see** things clearly.
- She helped me **see** things clearly.
- She helped us **be** there on time.

Or less often perhaps, with a gerund:

- She helps **arranging** things for us.
- She helped **arranging** things for us.

The construction *can help but INFINITIVE* is the same as *can only*, and again takes an infinitive:

- She cannot help but **smile** at her baby.
- She could not help but **smile** at her baby.
- She cannot help but **be** prim and proper.
- She could not help **but** be prim and proper.

It, too, can take a gerund complement:

- She can’t help **seeing** it his way.
- She couldn’t help **seeing** it his way.

Those are the same as these:

- She can’t help but **see** it his way.
- She couldn’t help **see** it his way.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence needs a comma to make sense of it:

*Tom **couldn't help**, but **cursed** when he saw Sam dressed like that.*

These are independent clauses joined by a conjunction and need a comma in N. America. 
The two verbs aren't really related. It not quite clear /whom/what situation/ Tom cannot help, but it may be well in the surrounding context.

Anyway, the meaning is different from the one of the second

*Tom **couldn't help but** **curse** when he saw Sam dressed like that.*

which uses the **"couldn't help but"**  idiom that combines the two verbs in a unit of meaning. I'm leaving the rest of the decrypting to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can say either

- **"Tom couldn't help cursing"**.

or

- **"Tom could not but curse"**.

These are idioms and you wouldn't change their structure.

EDit.
The Prescriptivist consider "Tom could not help but curse" a double negative, the same as "Tom couldn't not curse"